# Why do I get an Exception Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a very simple dll and load it to another file for learning purpose. I'm using VC++ same version for both the DLL and the C++ file. Here is my source code:

load.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef int(__stdcall* nsum)(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    HINSTANCE myDll = LoadLibrary(L".\\DLL1.dll");
    nsum sum = (nsum)GetProcAddress(myDll, "sum");

    if (!myDll) {
        cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    int xfinal = sum(10, 20);
    cout << xfinal << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and dll.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "pch.h"

using namespace std;

int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

pch.h

```
// pch.cpp: source file corresponding to the pre-compiled header

#include "pch.h"

// When you are using pre-compiled headers, this source file is necessary for compilation to succeed.
```

But still I'm getting the exception. I searched for answers but found none, so I am writing this for help

In the load.cpp, in HINSTANCE myDll, I can peek and see the value being set to 0x000000000. Is it the reason? If so, How can i fix it?

Comment: _Why do I get an Exception Exception thrown at 0x00000000_ 0x00000000 is usually not a valid address to write to. (It's "reserved" for the `nullptr`.) Hence, you may not read from or write to it (or the OS aborts your application with Access Violation).

Comment: @Scheff then what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Btw. you first use `myDll` and then check it's validity. If `myDll` isn't valid your application dies before the check. You should check in the debugger whether this is the essential issue or whether there are others as well.

Comment: @Scheff can you guide me on how to check that? Is it like debugging?

Comment: Have a specific look at the two code lines after `HINSTANCE myDll = LoadLibrary(L".\\DLL1.dll");`

Comment: FYI: [SO: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/7478597)

Comment: @Mayukh _"can you guide me on how to check that?"_ Just move the `if (!myDll) {` before any other usage of `myDll`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did that, and the if statement was not executed. But still I'm getting the Exception at `cout << xfinal ,<<endl; `

Comment: @Mayukh I am pretty sure your problem is actually here: `nsum sum = (nsum)GetProcAddress(myDll, "sum");`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is quite simple. The exported name of your function is not `sum` because you are *not* use a C [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).  Instead, it's a [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) name `?sum@@YGHHH@Z` which of course is not found by your use of `GetProcAddress(myDLL, "sum");` There is no such function *sum*. As such, you are trying to invoke a function at address 0, i.e. exactly what the exception tells you.

Microsoft calls these [Decorated Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names) rather than "mangled" but they both mean the same thing: the type information for the parameter types, calling-convention, and return value is encoded into special symbols that make up the name.

A few options here to fix this problem:

- Use the import library instead of explicit linking which will use the mangled name so you can stick with a C++ ABI.
- Use a C ABI via `extern "C"` keeping the existing `__stdcall` calling convention in which case the name will be `_sum@8` when building for x86 (32-bit):

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall sum(int a, int b)
```

- Use a C ABI with `extern "C"` but use `__cdecl` which will actually result in `sum` for x86 (32-bit):

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl sum(int a, int b)
```

For x64 there is one standard calling convention `__fastcall` (`__cdecl`, `__stdcall` are just aliases for `__fastcall`). In that, just using `extern "C"` will result in the name `sum` for any of those calling conventions. The only case that results in 'mangled' exports using a C ABI for x64 then is `extern "C" __vectorcall`.

> Be sure to update your typedef to match the calling convention you are using if you change it.

Second, you should add more error-checking:

```
HMODULE myDll = LoadLibrary(L".\\DLL1.dll");
if (!myDll) {
    cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

nsum sum = (nsum)GetProcAddress(myDll, "sum");
if (!sum) {
    cout << "could not find the export" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

> If you are using C++11 or later (Visual Studio 2012 or later), then `auto sum = reinterpret_cast<nsum>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(GetProcAddress(myDll, "sum")));` is better.

Comment: I am using VC++

Comment: @Mayukh Well, VC++ is feasible to use with the c++11 standard. You should try to sort out what exactly is what in your dev environment. VC++ is an IDE, not a compiler.